# How to overwrite \Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool

Tags: magento2, preference

***Short version***: 
How to use custom db and module config files instead of `env.php` and `config.php` ? or How to completely overwrite `\Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool` ?

***Long version***:
I'm developing a multi client system similar to https://github.com/elisei/Magento-Multi_Client.
I want to develop it in such a way that with one codebase, multiple databases can be installed. So multiple projects can be developed.

On code level following folders/files will be different for each project.

```
var/*
pub/*
app/etc/env.php 
app/etc/config.php
```

Instead of above I'll be using following folders/files:

```
var/client1/*
var/client2/*
pub/client1/*
pub/client2/*
app/etc/cliet1_env.php 
app/etc/cliet2_env.php 
app/etc/client1_config.php 
app/etc/client2_config.php
```

Based on the url used diferent database will be used (which will be done through setting host flags for each url). If url is `client1.com` , db used will use `cliet1_env.php`.

DB config file (`env.php`) which is used by default is mentioned in `Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool`, so I've overwritten this file in a custom module using preference. For clients1 here is the program.

`di.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool" type="Aceturtle\MultiClient\Config\File\ConfigFilePool"/>
</config>
```

and overwritten file

```
<?php

namespace Aceturtle\MultiClient\Config\File;

class ConfigFilePool extends \Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool {
   const APP_CONFIG = 'app_config';
    const APP_ENV = 'app_env';

    /**
     * Default files for configuration
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $applicationConfigFiles = [
        self::APP_CONFIG => 'client1_config.php',
        self::APP_ENV => 'client1_env.php',
    ];
    public function getPaths()
    {
        return $this->applicationConfigFiles;
    }
}
```

Call to `\Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool::getPaths()` is showing `client1_env.php` and  `client1_config.php` but still, If I print `\Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool` object it prints `client1_env.php`, `client1_config.php`, and `env.php`, `config.php` and if I run any command (module enable), it updates `config.php`, not `client1_config.php`. That means `\Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool` is not being completely overwritten.

How I can configure it such that my custom config files are used instead of default ones?

Comment: It's `private` variables how can u override?

Comment: Why you are doing such a way.
If you want to use separate DB for each website, why not create different magento setup for all. Hope you can understand.

Comment: I want to have a basic db config ready and just connect to it through above method. I do not want to create a new codebase instance again. Just modify module/theme according to my need.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use a Magento 2 plugin, for example, in a `etc/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool">
        <plugin name="extendGetterPlugin" type="Aceturtle\MultiClient\Plugin\ExtendGetterPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then under `Plugin/ExtendGetterPlugin.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Aceturtle\MultiClient\Plugin;

class ExtendGetterPlugin
{
    const APP_CONFIG = 'app_config';
    const APP_ENV = 'app_env';

    /**
     * Default files for configuration
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $applicationConfigFiles = [
        self::APP_CONFIG => 'client1_config.php',
        self::APP_ENV => 'client1_env.php',
    ];

    public function afterGetPaths(\Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool $subject, $result)
    {
        return $this->applicationConfigFiles;
    }
}
```

This way, you will override the result of the `getPaths` method via plugin.

Comment: @Raphal, it's throwing `[LogicException]                                                                                                                
  Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\App\Cache\State depends on Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\AccessProxy and vice versa.`

Comment: @amitshree interesting do you have the full trace ?

Comment: https://kobra.io/#/e/-KkQ6r7dNCTAlPVYe2hE

Comment: @amitshree interesting. It could be because the plugin system relies on the config pool files.

Answer (score 1):

U cannot override `private` variables.

When we run

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
<pre>Array
(
    [dist] => Array
        (
            [app_config] => config.dist.php
            [app_env] => env.dist.php
        )

    [local] => Array
        (
            [app_config] => config.local.php
            [app_env] => env.local.php
        )

)
```

So u have to apply changes in

```
 public function getInitialFilePools()
    {
        echo "1<pre>";
        print_r($this->initialConfigFiles);
        return $this->initialConfigFiles;
    }

public function getPath($fileKey)
{
    echo 2; exit;
    return client1_env.php; // Give dynamic logic over here
}
```

U have to overwrite value in Array in `getInitialFilePools` function

Comment: Tried this. It's not working.

Comment: In `public function getPath($fileKey)
    {
         return 'config_1.php;'
    }` & it works fine

Comment: here is the code I tried. https://kobra.io/#/e/-Kk9q2_JpDRR4pevG8Ui . Are you modifying core to test?

Comment: r u still facing issue? @amitshree

Comment: Yes. Kindly check my code shared above.

Answer (score 1):

We also ran into a similar issue. We wanted to rewrite some files that used in setup upgrade to optimize the deploy process. After some investigation, we found that these CLI commands are implemented independently of Magento using Symfony. It does not follow usual Magento execution cycle.

As a solution, we have created a module/script using the same method they have used in setup command namespace. The purpose of this module is to patch core files. The module can be used as composer hook or Magento CLI command.

You can find the module here. https://github.com/bgkavinga/magento2-patches

Hope this helps!